Colors for volume indicators
I am trying to generate the volume indicators with color. Red when the close is less than open and Green when Close is higher than open.
I am able to get the colors in candlestick but not in the volume section.
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
aapl <- quantmod::getSymbols("AAPL",
                             src = "yahoo",
                             from = "2020-01-01",
                             auto.assign = FALSE
    )
# Plot prices and volume with relative height.
highchart(type = "stock") %>%
    hc_title(text = "AAPLE") %>%
    hc_add_series(aapl, yAxis = 0, showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
    hc_add_yAxis(nid = 1L, title = list(text = "Prices"), relative = 2) %>%
    hc_add_series(aapl[, "AAPL.Volume"], yAxis = 1, type = "column", showInLegend = FALSE) %>% hc_add_yAxis(nid = 2L, title = list(text = "Volume"), relative = 1)%>% hc_plotOptions(
        candlestick=list(color= 'pink',
                         lineColor= 'red',
                         upColor= 'lightgreen',
                         upLineColor= 'green',
                         downColor = 'red',
                         downLineColor='red'))


Do you want the points from the volume series to change colors like the ones from the candlestick series? So if a point from the candlestick series is green, the column beneath should be green as well?

Yes that is correct. Right now all are blue.

Unfortunately such functionality is not available in Highcharts API. Still we can define the colors for each volume point seperately depending on the candlestick close/open values. A basic JS demo for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tm5k7pgj/
And the solution in R:
library(highcharter)

data <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date('2023-01-01') + 0:4,
  Open = c(100, 105, 102, 108, 110),
  High = c(110, 107, 108, 112, 115),
  Low = c(95, 100, 99, 105, 107),
  Close = c(105, 102, 108, 100, 113),
  Volume = c(1000, 1500, 1200, 1300, 1600)
)

hc_data <- lapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {
  list(
    as.numeric(as.POSIXct(data$Date[i])) * 1000,
    data$Open[i],
    data$High[i],
    data$Low[i],
    data$Close[i]
  )
})

hc_volume <- lapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {
  list(
    x = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(data$Date[i])) * 1000,
    y = data$Volume[i],
    color = ifelse(data$Close[i] > data$Open[i], 'green', 'red')    
  )
})

hchart <- highchart(type = "stock") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Candlestick and Volume Chart") %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(title = list(text = "OHLC"), height = "60%", lineWidth = 2),
    list(title = list(text = "Volume"), top = "65%", height = "35%", offset = 0, lineWidth = 2)
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(type = "candlestick", name = "AAPL", data = hc_data) %>%
  hc_add_series(type = "column", name = "Volume", data = hc_volume, yAxis = 1)%>%
  hc_plotOptions(candlestick = list(color = 'red', upColor = 'green', lineColor = 'red', upLineColor = 'green'))  


print(hchart)

In JS the core function looks like that:
const volumeData = data.map((item, index) => {
 const volume = item[5];
 const open = item[1];
 const close = item[4];
 const color = close > open ? 'green' : 'red';
 return {
  x: item[0],
  y: volume,
  color: color
}
});


Made the changes to hc_add_series for column as below:
hc_add_series(aapl[, "AAPL.Volume"], yAxis = 1, type = "column", showInLegend = FALSE,color = ifelse("AAPL.Close" > "AAPL.Open", "green", "red")) but it is showing all red. Can you suggest change

Oh sure, so maybe let's try to use a helper function to create the color vector and then pass it to the series. Here's the function: # Function to create the color vector
get_volume_colors <- function(open, close) {
ifelse(close > open, "green", "red")
} and rest: hc_add_series(data = data,
type = "column",
name = "Volume",
id = "volume",
colorByPoint = TRUE,
colors = get_volume_colors(data$Open, data$Close),
data = list_parse(data[c("Date", "Volume")]),
yAxis = 1) %>%

Unfortunately the highchart and does not allow data frame . The list_parse(data[c("Date", "Volume")]) is not working. Can you please suggest in its working.

Thanks for letting me know about that. I updated my answer with the whole R code that you only need to paste to your RStudio and it should work fine. Hope it helps!

It has worked as expected. Really appreciate your patience and help. Thanks once again.

I'm glad it worked, thanks for the kind words!
